# Java add remove methods of sets

Tags: java, methods, addition, set

Why does the method `add(<T> element)` and `remove(Object o)` accept different arguments?

For example in a `Set<Short>` you add short elements. Why does the method remove accepts `Object`? If you can't add any other data type, why would you remove other data type?

Thank you.

Comment: The JavaDoc explains this well: *Removes the specified element from this set if it is present (optional operation). More formally, removes an element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))*.

Comment: remove doesn't have to be quite so selective in the type of parameter required.

Answer (score 3):

`add(<T> element)` : to ensure that just a T element is added.

`remove(Object o)` : you can delete the T element even if it's a referenced by an Object reference.

For instance :

```
Set<Short> set = new HashSet<Short>();
Short number = 2;
set.add(number);
Object numberObject = number;
set.remove(numberObject) // it will remove 2 from the set.
```

why would you remove other data type? we're not removing another data type, but we can remove data even if it is referenced by an Object reference (like in the example).

Comment: we cannot instantiate a generic type

Comment: @Zeuzif, yes we cannot instantiate a generic type. 

T in my example was a class name, and I deleted it because it wasn't used.

Thanks and dima meghrib :)

Answer (score 0):

The `remove(obj)` method, removes the object such that `(obj == null ? e ==null : obj.equals(e))` is `true`. It's because of the `equals(Object)` method, which takes an `Object`, that `obj` and `e` doesn't have to be of the same type.