# java.util.Set add and remove method signature difference

Tags: java, set

When I see the Set.java file in JDK,

```
/**
 *
 * <p>This interface is a member of the
 * <a href="{@docRoot}/../technotes/guides/collections/index.html">
 * Java Collections Framework</a>.
 *
 * @param <E> the type of elements maintained by this set
 *
 * @author  Josh Bloch
 * @author  Neal Gafter
 * @see Collection
 * @see List
 * @see SortedSet
 * @see HashSet
 * @see TreeSet
 * @see AbstractSet
 * @see Collections#singleton(java.lang.Object)
 * @see Collections#EMPTY_SET
 * @since 1.2
 */
public interface Set<E> extends Collection<E> {
    /**
     * @param e element to be added to this set
     * @return <tt>true</tt> if this set did not already contain the specified
     *         element
     * @throws UnsupportedOperationException if the <tt>add</tt> operation
     *         is not supported by this set
     * @throws ClassCastException if the class of the specified element
     *         prevents it from being added to this set
     * @throws NullPointerException if the specified element is null and this
     *         set does not permit null elements
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if some property of the specified element
     *         prevents it from being added to this set
     */
    boolean add(E e);

     /**
     * @param o object to be removed from this set, if present
     * @return <tt>true</tt> if this set contained the specified element
     * @throws ClassCastException if the type of the specified element
     *         is incompatible with this set
     * (<a href="Collection.html#optional-restrictions">optional</a>)
     * @throws NullPointerException if the specified element is null and this
     *         set does not permit null elements
     * (<a href="Collection.html#optional-restrictions">optional</a>)
     * @throws UnsupportedOperationException if the <tt>remove</tt> operation
     *         is not supported by this set
     */
    boolean remove(Object o);

    //other methods
}
```

I am not getting, why `add` method is taking **`E`** parameter and `remove` method is taking **`Object`** parameter as a input argument?

Any help or reference link to understand this behavior would be appreciate.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17138241/java-add-remove-methods-of-sets

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why aren't Java Collections remove methods generic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104799/why-arent-java-collections-remove-methods-generic)

Answer (score 0):

Because your Set will always return E, but you may want to check if an object (not necessarily E) is in the Set.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, it's wierd, but it allows you to do the following:

```
Set<String> stringSet = new HashSet<String>();
stringSet.add("blah");

Object blah = "blah";
stringSet.remove(blah);
```

Comment: As its maps internally you need the "key" to remove, check my answer.

Comment: That makes no difference at all...the key is type 'E'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104799/why-arent-java-collections-remove-methods-generic?rq=1 Read answers here

Comment: So you're saying that the Set does it because the Map does it - that's a non-answer

Comment: That's definitely not what your answer says :P

Answer (score 0):

The `add` method of collections is 'covariant', which means that you can add any element of type `E` or of a subtype of `E`.
The `remove` method however is contravariant, you can remove any object that is a either of type `E` or of a supertype of `E`. Normally, the syntax would have to be

```
public boolean remove(? super E element)
```

But since this syntax is not valid in Java (unfortunately), the type of the parameter is `Object`, which is always a super type of `E`, no matter what `E` is.

This also allows you to remove an object from the collection whose runtime type is `E` while its compile-time type is a supertype of `E`. For example, take a look at this simple piece of code

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList();
list.add("abc");

Object o = "abc";
list.remove(o);
```

This code shows that you should be able to remove any object from the collection that has the same or a supertype of the collection.
Due to the syntactic limitation of Java, the method would also accept any other object that could never be in the collection due to its type:

```
list.remove(1);
```

This example compiles perfectly fine, but it makes no sense: You could never have an Integer in your `List<String>`.

**Conclusion**

The parameter type of `remove` is `Object` because it represents the supertype of all types, and it lets you remove an element that has been upcasted to `Object` while it could still be an element in the collection due to its runtime type.
The signature `remove(? super E)` is neither possible nor necessary, but it would warn the programmer when an operation can never succeed, like `remove(1)` on a `List<String>`.

Comment: where did you get this explanation?

Comment: I don't have any actual source, but it's the most logical explanation. I will edit my answer to explain it.

Comment: I understand your idea, but I think it is not true about supertypes. It is mostly about safetness and backward compatibility.

Comment: Are you sure it couldn't be `public <T super E> boolean remove(T element)`?

Comment: Might be because of safety and backwards compatibility in Java, but the signature should be `remove(? super E)` in a world where this syntax is possible. That way, the compiler could warn you about `remove` operations that will always fail, like `stringList.remove(1)`.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce unfortunately, this is also invalid syntax, but it represents the same thing as `remove(? super E)`.

Comment: huh, it **is** invalid syntax. I guess you can only use `extends` in generic methods. Well, at least I learned something new.

Comment: When writing a collection library, I also had to learn this the hard way while trying to write my `remove` methods. This is why I came up with the `remove(? super E)` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

In `public boolean add(E e)` E means the the type of elements maintained by this set. You can only permitted element of type  in collection. Inernally its maps at work

```
 public boolean add(E e) {
        return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
    }
```

In `public boolean remove(Object o)` Removes the specified element from this set if it is present. You dont need to check what type of element it is - just check if its there take it out.

again maps at work internally

```
 public boolean remove(Object o) {
        return map.remove(o)==PRESENT;
    }
```