# Should remove(Object) be remove(? super E)

Tags: java, generics, collections, super, contravariance

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30781910/4138801), I tried to explain why the Collection method `add` has the signature `add(E)` while `remove` is `remove(Object)`. I came up with the idea that the correct signature should be

```
public boolean remove(? super E element)
```

And since this is invalid syntax in Java, they had to stick to `Object`, which just happens to be `super E` (supertype of `E`) for any `E`. The following code explains why this makes sense:

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList();
strings.add("abc");

Object o = "abc"; // runtime type is String
strings.remove(o);
```

Since the runtime type is String, this succeeds. If the signature were `remove(E)`, this would cause an error at compile-time but not at runtime, which makes no sense. However, the following *should* raise an error at compile time, because the operation is bound to fail because of its types, which are known at compile-time:

```
strings.remove(1);
```

The `remove` takes an `Integer` as an argument, which is *not* `super String`, which means it could never actually remove anything from the collection.

If the `remove` method was defined with the parameter type `? super E`, situations like the above could be detected by the compiler.

***Question***:

Am I correct with my theory that `remove` should have a contravariant `? super E` parameter instead of `Object`, so that type mismatches as shown in the above example can be filtered out by the compiler? And is it correct that the creators of the Java Collections Framework chose to use `Object` instead of `? super E` because `? super E` would cause a syntax error, and instead of complicating the generic system they simply agreed to use `Object` instead of `super`?

Also, should the signature for `removeAll` be

```
public boolean removeAll(Collection<? super E> collection)
```

---

Note that I *do not* want to know why the signature is not `remove(E)`, which is asked and explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104799). I want to know if `remove` should be contravariant (`remove(? super E)`), while `remove(E)` represents covariance.

---

One example where this does *not* work would be the following:

```
List<Number> nums = new ArrayList();
nums.add(1);
nums.remove(1); // fails here - Integer is not super Number
```

Rethinking my signature, it should actually allow sub- *and* supertypes of `E`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why aren't Java Collections remove methods generic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104799/why-arent-java-collections-remove-methods-generic)

Comment: This is not a duplicate, as I want to know if the `remove` method should be contravariant, while the question is about why it is not `remove(E)` (which is covariant for `E` and subtypes).

Comment: @tobias_k you can try that out... (it gives you a nice syntax error at `T super E`, because type variables can only use `extends`)

Comment: See the answer here http://smallwig.blogspot.ru/2007/12/why-does-setcontains-take-object-not-e.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a faulty assumption:

> because the operation is bound to fail because of its types, which are known at compile-time

It's the same reasoning that `.equals` accepts an object: objects don't necessarily need to have the same class in order to be equal. Consider this example with different subtypes of List, as pointed out in [the question @Joe linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104799/why-arent-java-collections-remove-methods-generic?lq=1):

```
List<ArrayList<?>> arrayLists = new ArrayList<>();
arrayLists.add(new ArrayList<>());

LinkedList<?> emptyLinkedList = new LinkedList<>();
arrayLists.remove(emptyLinkedList); // removes the empty ArrayList and returns true
```

This would not be possible with the signature you proposed.

Comment: "This would not be possible with the signature you proposed." **Why not simply make another overload for Collection<E>?**

Comment: @AnuragAwasthi That doesn't solve the underlying issue. What if its not a collection but another arbitrary supertype?

Answer (score 3):

`remove(? super E)` is *entirely* equivalent to `remove(Object)`, because `Object` is itself a supertype of `E`, and all objects extend `Object`.

Comment: Not entirely: `stringList.remove(1)` would fail with `? super E` because `Integer` is *not* `super String`. But as you can read in my note in the original question, `super` is not the perfect solution either.

Comment: Nope.  `1` is _also_ an `Object`, and `Object` is a supertype of `E`.

Comment: Yes, yes, yes. I know that you could do `Object o = 1; stringList.remove(o)` and that would be perfectly fine with `Object super String`, but for `remove(1)`, the type of the parameter is clearly `Integer`. And this is a case that simply makes no sense as you can't remove an integer from a list of strings anyway, and thus it should be reported by the compiler.

Comment: Also, can you call a `foo(List<? super String>)` with a `List<Integer>` because 'Integer is also an Object'? That defeats the whole purpose of `super`.

Comment: @Clashsoft: the compiler would disagree with you; all parameters can always be converted to their supertypes.

Comment: @Clashsoft: no, because a `List<Integer>` is not a subtype of `List<Object>`.

Comment: The *current* compiler, which just happens to *not* support `? super E`. If that was a thing, it wouldn't let you call `stringList.remove(1)`. And this my friend is the whole purpose of my question.

Comment: @Clashsoft `? super E` has an upper bound of `Object`, though. That is the way it works right now. Basically what you described in the question is not what the `super` bound does. Bounded wildcards are only needed in the first place because of the way generic subtyping works.

Comment: While I agree with you, `super` in my case is not really a generic bound. It simply means 'anything that has type E or a supertype of that'. In fact, `super` is not even correct here, as it should be `super` and `extends` at the same time (note in the question). 'has type E' implies 'E or subtypes of E'.

Comment: "If that was a thing, it wouldn't let you call stringList.remove(1)." It absolutely would.

Answer (score 2):

I think that designers of the collections framework made a decision to keep `remove` untyped, because it is a valid solution that lets you keep a post-condition without introducing a pre-condition or compromising type safety.

The post-condition of a `c.remove(x)` is that after the call `x` is not present in `c`. Method signature `remove(Object)` lets you pass any object or `null`, with no further checks. Method signature `? super E`, on the other hand, introduces a pre-condition on the type of `x`, requiring it to be related to `E`.

Each pre-condition that you introduce in an API makes your API harder to use. If removing a pre-condition lets you keep all your post-conditions, it is a good idea to remove the pre-condition.

Note that removing an object of a wrong type is not necessarily an error. Here is a small example:

```
class Segregator {
    private final Set<Integer> ints = ...
    private final Set<String> strings = ...
    public void addAll(List<Object> data) {
        for (Object o : data) {
            if (o instanceof Integer) {
                ints.add((Integer)o);
            }
            if (o instanceof String) {
                strings.add((String)o);
            }
        }
    }
    // Here is the method that becomes easier to write:
    public void removeAll(List<Object> data) {
        for (Object o : data) {
            ints.remove(o);
            strings.remove(o);
        }
    }
}
```

Note how `removeAll` method's code is simpler than the code of `addAll`, because `remove` does not care about the type of the object that you pass to it.

Comment: Your `removeAll` method still works with `remove(? super E)`, since `? super Integer` *and* `? super String` is true for `Object o`.

Comment: @Clashsoft I guess I could have picked unrelated classes for the illustration. My point was that it is OK to allow deletion of things that could not possibly have been inserted in the first place, because it makes use of your class simpler.

Comment: True, but also more 'dangerous' (in terms of potential programming errors that could be reported if `? super E` was a thing)

Answer (score 0):

In your question you already explained why it can't (or shouldn't) be `remove(E)`.

But there is also a reason why it shouldn't be `remove(? super E)`. Imagine some piece of code where you have an object of unknown type. You still might want to try to remove that object from that list. Consider this code:

```
public void removeFromList(Object o, Collection<String> col) {
    col.remove(o);
}
```

Now your argument was, that `remove(? super E)` is more typesafe way. But I say it doesn't have to be. Look at the [Javadoc of remove()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#remove(java.lang.Object)). It says:

> More formally, removes an element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)), if this collection contains one or more such elements.

So all the preconditions the parameter has to match is that you can use `==` and `equals()` on it, which is the case with `Object`. This still enables you to try to remove an `Integer` from a `Collection<String>`. It just wouldn't do anything.

Comment: Well, your example would work as `Object super String`. It is not about the fact that `remove` would fail with an incorrect type (it won't), but it would be possible to filter programming problems like `stringList.remove(1)` before they even arise, by allowing a nice compiler error because of incompatible types.

Comment: @Clashsoft Allright, bad example. Still my last paragraph counts. Such a case could be accidental but you might be able to think of cases where this is on purpose. Gotta go for now, will try to find a better example later on.

Comment: In these cases you could cast to `Object` and everything would work again, as `Object super E` no matter what.